# Requisições REST com HTTPS

Tags: java, rest, restful, wildfly, https

Bom dia pessoal,

Alguém consegue tirar uma dúvida... é o seguinte:
Tenho uma aplicação que está dentro de um domínio com certificado (HTTPS).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quando vou consumir um serviço REST, eu tenho o retorno 405 e no navegador é informado que a conexão não é segura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que o meu método é POST e acessando esta URL no navegador será retornado o status HTTP 405... a pergunta é: O retorno 405 não deveria ser enviado usando uma conexão segura?

Comment: O Status 405 é por que o Método de acesso não está criado.
Ex: Você está fazendo uma request POST, quando o único Método criado éo GET.
Ou ainda 
Você está acessando o GET e o único aceitável é o POST.

Comment: Olá Lucas, tudo tranquilo?
Eu sei porque estou recebendo o 405 (isso não é o problema)... a dúvida é referente a "conexão não segura" quando a aplicação retorna esse status. gostaria de saber se é um comportamento padrão ou se tem alguma coisa errada.